# nested Math.Pow(...) acting weird

Tags: c#, math, nested, pow

Currently I'm rewriting some old C++ code to C#. When running some tests it didn't work as it should, and I started debugging, and came across the below which I cant seem to figure out.

As I'm doing a lot of math in the class and using Math.Pow function very often, I created a shortcut method for it:

```
public double pow(double d, double p)
{
   return Math.Pow(d,p);
}
```

Then I have a code line as follows, which use this method quite some times:

```
double y = pow((pow(d12, 2) + pow(d13, 2) + pow(23, 2)), 2) - (2.0 * (pow(d12, 4) + pow(d13, 4) + pow(d23, 4)));
```

This line didn't give the expected result, so I started splitting it up into smaller pieces as it should be calculated... for example the value before the minus sign should be equal to q5:

```
double q1 = pow(d12, 2);
double q2 = pow(d13, 2);
double q3 = pow(d23, 2);
double q4 = q1 + q2 + q3;
double q5 = pow(q4, 2);
```

After these lines q5 is 8775553070736.0

Then I tried splitting the long line into two parts, where the first should be equal to the above 5 lines, just written as one line:

```
double q12 = pow((pow(d12, 2) + pow(d13, 2) + pow(23, 2)), 2);
```

Which I would expect to evaluate to the same as q5, but it does not. q12 instead evaluates to 4479508755225.0

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: by the way, `Math.Pow` is quite slow. I would suggest using `double sqr(double d) { return d * d; }` and `double fourthPow(double d) { return d*d*d*d; }`.

Comment: You shot your foot.  That happens when use variable names like "q5" and "d23".  Use better names.

Comment: I am not certain of the inner-workings of pow() but I suspect d12*d12 would be faster than pow(d12,2)

Comment: Thanks for the performance tip Vlad - I guess I will do that change right away.
Indeed Hans - names would be better, but I need a lot of different variables, and the numbers after a letter help me to see what the variable represent. Changing VS number highlights as suggested in the answer below might help a lot though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you expect:

```
pow(d23, 2)
```

to be the same as

```
pow(23, 2)
```

?

**PROTIP:** IN VS, always change the default colour of numbers (black), to something else (I like red).

Comment: I knew I just missed a parathese or something, and couldnt see it as I stared at it too long... but indeed - that was the error I missed. Will accept your answer as I am allowed.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for that tip aswell - will indeed do that.